# Click event in AngularJs Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-google-maps

I am using http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps and I am not able to catch the event of simple click on the map.

I tried it like this:

```
_scope.map = {
    center: { latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude },
    zoom: 16,
    events: {
       click: function(mapModel, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
            console.log("user defined event: " + eventName, mapModel, originalEventArgs);
            var e = originalEventArgs[0];
            _scope.$apply();
       }
    }
};

<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom"></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

I doesn't work like this and I don't know what to do. I would like to be able to get the coordinates of the clicked location. Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't bind `event` property of `<ui-gmap-google-map>` directive to the variable (associative array) map.events...
So you should do:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" events="map.events" zoom="map.zoom"></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Comment: I have a working implementation in my web app (angularJS + TypeScript). but the same code doesn't work on a cordova Ionic v1 app. setting up the map, adding markers etc. all work fine, except for map events. they don't even fire up. any ideas?